# How compiler allocates memory to the array of unspecified dimension?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Ex. `char s[]="Hello";`

As per my knowledge, string constants are stored in stack memory and array with unspecified dimension are stored in heap memory. How memory will be allocated to above statement?

Comment: Is that a local or global variable?

Comment: `s[]` is an array initialized with the *literal* `"Hello"`. The compiler knows the size of `"Hello"` to begin with. There is nothing dynamic about the initialization or storage. That is a valid initializer that initializes `s` as `{ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };`

Comment: The code shown won't allocate any memory; a string literal is not an appropriate initializer for an array of `int` (but it would be fine for an array of `char`).  I'm also puzzled about your claim that string constants are stored in stack memory — that isn't where I'd expect to find them.

Comment: Ahh -- funny what the mind will overlook when it is expecting something logical...

Comment: In this case, the dimension IS specified if `s` is an array of char -  `"Hello"` is used to initialise `s`, and the dimension is `sizeof("Hello"`)  i.e. `6`.    For `s` being an array of `int`, the code won't compile.

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'int []'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the statement:

```
int s[]="Hello";
```

is incorrect. Compiler will report error on it because here you are trying to initialize `int` array with `string`.

The below part of the answer is based on assumption that there is a typo and correct statement is:

```
char s[]="Hello";
```

> As per my knowledge, string constants are stored in stack memory and array with unspecified dimension are stored in heap memory.

I would say you need to change the source from where you get knowledge.

String constants (*also called string literals*) are not stored in stack memory. If not in the stack then where? Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go).

In the statement:

```
char s[]="Hello";
```

there will not be any memory allocation but this is `char` array initialized with a string constant.
Whenever we write a string, enclosed in double quotes, C automatically creates an array of characters for us, containing that string, terminated by the `\0` character.

If we omit the dimension, compiler computes it for us based on the size of the initializer (here it is 6, including the terminating `\0` character).

So the given statement is equivalent to this:

```
char s[]={'H','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

Can also be written as:

```
char s[6]={'H','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```